# Cypress.io + TypeScript. Assertion call in beginning of test

Tags: typescript, assertion, browser-automation, cypress

I am new to Cypress.io and TypeScript. So I do not understood some stuff here.

My code:

```
//Test
describe('TEST description', function () {
it('newJobCreation', function () {
    //Some code 1
    var numberBefore = cy.get('#idOfItem')
    var _numberBefore = +numberBefore
    //Some code 2

    var numberAfter = cy.get('#idOfItem')
    var _numberAfter = +numberAfter
    //Assertion
    expect(_numberBefore-1).equals(_numberAfter) //Same result if I use: assert.equal(_numberBefore-1, _numberAfter)
   }) 
})
```

Lets say _numberBefore after //Some code2 was changed and become _numberAfter. I want to assert that number decreased by 1.

After I running test in Cypress.io, I am getting error message:

> expected NaN to equal NaN

and it fails.

**Question:**

Why my assertion does not call after all code was executed? Why it was called in a beginning of test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypress asynchronously queues your commands all at once. This means that

```
let elem = cy.get("#elem");
// attempt to do something with returned element...
```

will not work. `cy.get()` just tells Cypress to add the `get()` command to the list of commands to eventually be run. It does not run the command right away.

`.then()` provides a nice alternative - you can use it to queue up some Javascript to be run when the command is run, like so:

```
cy.get("#elem1").then(elem1 => {
    // elem1 is the underlying DOM object.

    // You can put regular javascript code here:
    console.log("This will happen when the queued .then() command is run");

    // You can also put more Cypress commands here, like so:
    cy.get("#elem2").should(elem2 => {
        expect(elem1.someProperty).to.equal(elem2.someProperty);
    });
});
```

Note that `.should(() => {})` acts like a `.then()`, except it will retry if any contained assertions fail.

See [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Closures) for more info on comparing values of two elements to each other, and see [this doc page](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html) for more info on the general concepts of asynchronous command queuing in Cypress.

Comment: Everything is all right, just for example code must be like this: 

`cy.get('#idOfItem').then(($numberBefore) =>{
     const txt = $numberBefore.text()
     var _numberBefore = +txt
     //Some code 1
     cy.get('#idOfItem').should(($numberAfter) => {
    const txt2 = $numberAfter.text()
    var _numberAfter = +txt2
    expect(_numberBefore-1).to.equal(_numberAfter)
   })
})`

Variable need to be in "()" brackets.

P.s. thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're talking about the `() => {}` anonymous function style, `someVar => {}` is actually valid. You need parenthesis if there are no arguments, or if there is more than one argument, but if there's just one argument you can leave out the `()`. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89L6bcw7/4/) for a working example.