# Cypress.io: Reading and storing value of form input into a JS variable (or constant)

Tags: automated-tests, forms, cypress

I have an HTML form (really simple one, no tricky parts like Ajax, ...) on a simple page. I try to read default value of any input (type="text", again no tricks) and store it in constant for later use (assert).

HTML looks like:

```
<form method="post" ...>
  <input type="text" id="xyz" name="xyz" value="123">
</form>
```

Cypress test, that DOESN'T work, looks like:

```
describe('General tests', function(){

  context('General', function() {

    it('can read the input and store in const', function () {

        cy.visit('http://localhost/settings')
        const xyz = Cypress.$('#xyz').val()
        cy.log(xyz)

    })

  })
})
```

This doesn't work. BUT after several hours of playing (by accident this worked for me in more complex test suite = file). What I realized is, that this construct works as expected in case previous test ( = it() ) visits the same URL as the last visited URL. Than it works like a miracle.

Cypress test, that WORKS, looks like:

```
describe('General tests', function(){

  context('General', function() {

    it('makes magic and allows the next test to work', function () {

        cy.visit('http://localhost/settings')

    })

    it('can read the input and store in const', function () {

        cy.visit('http://localhost/settings')
        const xyz = Cypress.$('#xyz').val()
        cy.log(xyz)

    })

  })
})
```

I thought that tests should be independent, but it looks like they are not.

I tried other ways how to get the value of input info variable and the closest what I needed was using closure ".then()", but it can be used for just a single input, not for more complex forms.

Simple asserting like "cy.get('#id_of_input').should('eq', ...)" works fine, but it doesn't allow me to work with default (and by test overridden) value of inputs.

So my questions:

1) Is it OK to use included jQuery in this way to get and store value of input into constant? If now what is the other way for cases when I need to do this for like 5 various input fields in the form (for a signel input closure will be just fine)
2) Is it OK that tests influence each other?

Thanks everyone for any help.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your questions:

---

1)  According to the docs, `Cypress.$` is "a great way to *synchronously* query for elements". (emphasis theirs)

The way you're using it circumvents the intended Cypress workflow with asynchronous command queuing. If you don't know what I'm talking about here, I suggest reading the [fantastic introduction to Cypress in their documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#).

I would suggest the following as an alternative to the code you posted:

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost/settings');
cy.get('#xyz').then(elem => {
    // elem is the underlying Javascript object targeted by the .get() command.
    const xyz = Cypress.$(elem).val();
    cy.log(xyz);
});
```

`.then().` lets you queue up code to be run in sequence with your test by the test runner. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51754918/8166701) for more info about command queuing and `.then()`.

---

2) Yes, it is okay for `describe` functions to influence each other. Cypress runs each *file* separately, but separate describes are simply run in the sequence they are queued in.

For example, the following code will work just fine:

```js
let message = "";

describe("Set a value", () => {
    it("Sets a value", () => {
        message = "hi";
    });
});

describe("Retrieve a value", () => {
    it("Retrieves and prints the set value", () => {
        cy.log(message); // Logs "hi" to the Cypress log window
    });
});
```

Comment: If You're using typescript, You can use tslint-plugin-cypress to prevent mistakes like this - https://github.com/krzysztof-grzybek/tslint-plugin-cypress